# How to find the position of a given image in the video time frame

Tags: image, video, hash, video-processing

I was given two inputs one is an image taken with a cell phone. And the other is a video file. The image is taken from the monitor while video is playing.
If you have these two inputs can you find the exact location of the image in the video time frame.

as an example:

here is an image captured at the time 10:00 of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=630Q9mVfE48

[image]

Thanks
Nuri

Comment: **Depends on the inputs**. Why worry if a "you" (or me) can find it? How is this a **programming** question? If you have pixels you want to advice about, then please show them (or else show close/similar examples, if input is private content). You could "recreate" the photo using some other Youtube video and ask here _"how to find this image"_ (show it) _"in this video"_ (show youtube link)...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I will create a sample image and provide  the video

Comment: this is CBIR, matching one image against all frames of a video... no trivial solution. that means you have to know the theory and implement it yourself.

Comment: Is there any similarity with the shazam technology?

Comment: What if the video contains non-unique frames (e.g., a static title slide that is up for several seconds)? The problem is more complex than it seems at a first glance.